# In Swift Combine, is the "root" object always a Subject?

Tags: swift, swift5, combine

In Apple's WWDC videos on `Swift Combine`, they always use `NSNotificationCenter` as the publisher of messages. However, a `Publisher` does not appear to have any ability to actually send a message on demand. That functionality appears to be in `Subject`.

Am I correct in assuming that a `Subject` must therefor be the root object of any chain of `Publishers`? Apple provides two built-in subjects called: `CurrentValueSubject` and `PassthroughSubject`.

But I assume I can write my own `Subject` using the appropriate protocols?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift Combine, *Publishers* are a protocol describing an object which can transmit values over time.

A Subject is an extended publisher which knows how to send imperatively.

Neither Publisher nor Subject are concrete classes with implementation; they are both protocols.

Take a look at the Publisher protocol (and remember that a Subject is an extended Publisher):

```
public protocol Publisher {

    associatedtype Output

    associatedtype Failure : Error

    func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Self.Failure == S.Failure, Self.Output == S.Input
}
```

To build a custom publisher you need only implement the receive function (and provide type information), in which you are given access to a subscriber. How would you send data to that subscriber from WITHIN the publisher?

For this we look at the Subscriber protocol to see what's available:

```
public protocol Subscriber : CustomCombineIdentifierConvertible {
...

    /// Tells the subscriber that the publisher has produced an element.
    ///
    /// - Parameter input: The published element.
    /// - Returns: A `Demand` instance indicating how many more elements the subcriber expects to receive.
    func receive(_ input: Self.Input) -> Subscribers.Demand
}
```

As long as you've saved a reference to any/all subscribers which have connected, your publisher can easily send changes into the pipeline by calling `receive` on the subscriber. However, you'll have to manage subscribers and diff changes on your own.

A Subject behaves the same but instead of streaming changes into the pipeline, it simply provides a `send` function for someone else to call. The two concrete Subjects that Swift provides have additional features like storage.

TL;DR changes aren't sent to *publishers* they're sent to subscribers. Subjects are publishers that can accept some input.

Comment: Right, but I must be missing something obvious because I can't see how a message is actually sent to a publisher without a `Subject`. I can see how it gets passed on once it's in the chain, but only the `Subject` protocol has a `send()` method on it. If I have a custom class that I want to broadcast changes from, then the `Publisher` that I expose for others to subscribe to must need to actually be a `Subject`, otherwise how does my custom class actually send a message to the subscribers?

Comment: Big thanks. The part I'm still confused on is how all of the chaining of publishers comes into play. I have a custom class that is a Publisher. It keeps track of each Subscriber it receives in an array. When it wants to send a message, it iterates the array and calls `receive()` on each `Subscriber`. That's basically the old Obj-C delegate pattern with multiple delegates. How does my custom Publisher expose itself so that either I can chain with things like `debounce()` or a `Subscriber` can create their own `Publisher` chain.

Comment: Composition is done using Operators, which accept an input Publisher and an output Subscriber. Apple has extended the Publisher protocol to add functions for common operators (chaining), but if you're constructing your own operators you will need to manually subscribe to the publisher and add a downstream subscriber. E.g. simply initialize a debounce Operator and hook it up (or use .debounce() on a Publisher).

Comment: I will. It still doesn't make sense to me how the operators are connected. If my custom class is a `Publisher` and has references to all its `Subscribers` then as noted above it just calls `receive` on each `Subscriber`. If my class creates a `debounce` operator and hooks up each `Subscriber` to it, then how does my class "send" a message through the `debounce` operator which would then send it to each `Subscriber`? If I use a `Subject` as the root object from within my custom class it makes sense, but not when my class is a `Publisher` itself.

Comment: The Debounce is the subscriber that your publisher has access to, so anytime you call `receive` you're actually sending data to the debounce, not your subscriber. Put another way the Operator is both a subscriber (to your publisher) as well as a Publisher (to your subscriber, or to the next operator in the chain). Gonna need to see code to help any further on that but usually Operators are external to a Publisher (unless you're just wrapping an existing publisher).

Comment: "...the Operator is both a subscriber as well as a Publisher...", well there's the missing piece of the puzzle. I see now that if I "chain" one of the operators to my custom Publisher that my `receive` method is called with the operator as a `Subscriber`. With that and your comments above about just calling `receive` on a `Subscriber` it makes sense. I still don't see in the headers where something like `Debounce` explicitly conforms to `Subscriber`. Regardless, thanks for your patience and follow-up.